# Pygame object has no attribute 'rect' (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, attributes

I'm currently making Memory, a game for school which involves matching 8 pairs of images that are hidden underneath covers. I was successful in setting up the 4x4 grid, with a timer for score and randomizing the location of the images, but removing the cover on the tiles is giving me some issues. I end up getting the error: builtins.AttributeError: type object 'Tile' has no attribute 'rect'

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/Lab 4/memory2cover.py", line 179, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/Documents/Lab 4/memory2cover.py", line 21, in <module>
    game.play()
  File "/home/user/Documents/Lab 4/memory2cover.py", line 92, in <module>
    self.handle_events()
  File "/home/user/Documents/Lab 4/memory2cover.py", line 117, in <module>
    Tile.handle_click(Tile, event)
  File "/home/user/Documents/Lab 4/memory2cover.py", line 175, in <module>
    if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
builtins.AttributeError: type object 'Tile' has no attribute 'rect'
```

My Tile class is:

```
class Tile:
   # An object in this class represents a Tile 
   # Shared or Class Attributes
   surface = None
   fg_color = pygame.Color('black')
   border_width = 10
   cover = pygame.image.load('image0.bmp')

   @classmethod
   def set_surface(cls,surface_from_Game):
      cls.surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

   def __init__(self, x,y,width,height, image):
      # Initialize a Tile.
      # - self is the Tile to initialize
      # - x,y top left coordinates of the rectangle
      # - - width, height are the dimensions of the rectangle
      # Instance Attributes or Object Attributes
      self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
      self.image = image
      self.covered = True

   def draw(self):
      # Draw the dot on the surface
      # - self is the Tile
      # then blit the tile content onto the surface
      pygame.draw.rect(Tile.surface, Tile.fg_color, self.rect,Tile.border_width)
      if self.covered:
         Tile.surface.blit(Tile.cover, self.rect)
      else:
         Tile.surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

   def handle_click(self, event):
      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
         pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
         if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.covered = False
```

and I am not too sure why it is saying it has no attribute 'rect'.

Here is my full code

```
# Memory 1

import pygame
import random

# User-defined functions
# board[row_index][col_index]

def main():
   # initialize all pygame modules (some need initialization)
   pygame.init()
   # create a pygame display window
   pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
   # set the title of the display window
   pygame.display.set_caption('Memory')   
   # get the display surface
   w_surface = pygame.display.get_surface() 
   # create a game object
   game = Game(w_surface)
   # start the main game loop by calling the play method on the game object
   game.play() 
   # quit pygame and clean up the pygame window
   pygame.display.quit()
   pygame.quit() 


# User-defined classes

class Game:
   # An object in this class represents a complete game.

   def __init__(self, surface):
      # Initialize a Game.
      # - self is the Game to initialize
      # - surface is the display window surface object

      # === objects that are part of every game that we will discuss
      self.surface = surface
      self.bg_color = pygame.Color('black')

      self.FPS = 70
      self.game_Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
      self.close_clicked = False
      self.continue_game = True

      # === game specific objects
      Tile.set_surface(self.surface) # this is how you call a class method
      self.board_size = 4
      self.board = []
      self.score = 0
      self.load_images()
      self.create_board()
      self.image_index = 0


   def load_images(self):
      # loads a specified amount of images into a list
      # that list of images is then shuffled so an images index is randomized
      self.image_list = []
      for self.image_index in range(1,9):
         self.image_list.append(pygame.image.load('image' + str(self.image_index) + '.bmp'))
      self.full_list = self.image_list + self.image_list
      random.shuffle(self.full_list)

   def create_board(self):
      # multiple rows and columns are appended to the board with the tiles added
      # utlizes the different images for each tile
      index = 0
      img = self.full_list[0]
      width = img.get_width()
      height = img.get_height()
      for row_index in range(0,self.board_size):
         self.row = []
         for col_index in range(0,self.board_size):
            #item = (row_index,col_index)
            # game = Game(), dot1 = Dot(), student = Student()
            image = self.full_list[index]
            x = width * col_index
            y = height * row_index      
            a_tile = Tile(x,y,width,height, image)
            self.row.append(a_tile)
            index = index + 1
         self.board.append(self.row)


   def play(self):
      # Play the game until the player presses the close box.
      # - self is the Game that should be continued or not.

      while not self.close_clicked:  # until player clicks close box
         # play frame
         self.handle_events()
         self.draw()            
         if self.continue_game:
            self.update()
         self.game_Clock.tick(self.FPS) # run at most with FPS Frames Per Second 

   def draw_score(self):
      fg = pygame.Color('white')
      bg = pygame.Color('black')
      font = pygame.font.SysFont('',70)
      text_box = font.render(str(self.score),True,fg,bg)
      #x = self.surface.get_width() - text_box.get_width()
      #y = self.surface.get_height() - text_box.get_height()
      location = (self.surface.get_width() -70,0)
      self.surface.blit(text_box,location)   

   def handle_events(self):
      # Handle each user event by changing the game state appropriately.
      # - self is the Game whose events will be handled

      events = pygame.event.get()
      for event in events:
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.close_clicked = True
         for item in self.row:
            Tile.handle_click(Tile, event)

   def draw(self):
      # Draw all game objects.
      # - self is the Game to draw
      coordinates = self.create_board()

      # clear the display surface first
      self.surface.fill(self.bg_color) 
      # drawing of the board
      for row in self.board:
         for tile in row:
            tile.draw()
      self.draw_score()
      pygame.display.update() # make the updated surface appear on the display

   def update(self):
      # Update the game objects for the next frame.
      # - self is the Game to update
      self.score = pygame.time.get_ticks()//1000



class Tile:
   # An object in this class represents a Tile 
   # Shared or Class Attributes
   surface = None
   fg_color = pygame.Color('black')
   border_width = 10
   cover = pygame.image.load('image0.bmp')

   @classmethod
   def set_surface(cls,surface_from_Game):
      cls.surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

   def __init__(self, x,y,width,height, image):
      # Initialize a Tile.
      # - self is the Tile to initialize
      # - x,y top left coordinates of the rectangle
      # - - width, height are the dimensions of the rectangle
      # Instance Attributes or Object Attributes
      self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
      self.image = image
      self.covered = True

   def draw(self):
      # Draw the dot on the surface
      # - self is the Tile
      # then blit the tile content onto the surface
      pygame.draw.rect(Tile.surface, Tile.fg_color, self.rect,Tile.border_width)
      if self.covered:
         Tile.surface.blit(Tile.cover, self.rect)
      else:
         Tile.surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

   def handle_click(self, event):
      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
         pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
         if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.covered = False


main()
```

Comment: Please update this question with respect to [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We expect code that will reproduce the problem, as well as the *full* error message -- including the traceback.  You've left us having to guess where in 30 lines of code the problem arises, as well as what variable or argument values provoked the problem.

Comment: Please include the code where `Tile.draw()` is being called.

Comment: Added the full code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
Tile.handle_click( Tile, event )
```

The code is confusing the class definition of the `Tile` object, with an instantiated object - like a "live copy" of it ~ `a_tile`.  So when it calls `Tile.something()`, the `__init__()` has never been called, so `.rect` does not exist.  Of course `a_tile` has a `.rect`, because it has been instantiated.

It should probably be something like:

```
   def handle_events(self):
      # Handle each user event by changing the game state appropriately.
      # - self is the Game whose events will be handled

      events = pygame.event.get()
      for event in events:
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.close_clicked = True
         for item in self.row:
            item.handle_click( event )    # <-- HERE
```

Except for `@classmethod` functions (i.e.: what every other language calls `static` member functions), member functions are almost never called on the class definition.  So if you find yourself writing `Tile.something` to call a function, you should be questioning yourself.

Unless you have an object with no internal state, it's normal to have none-to-few @classmethod functions.  Sometimes you might do a class, say a unit-converter, which is in an object simply to collect a whole bunch of small functions together.  These would all be called on the definition, e.g.:  `Units.furlongsToMetres( fur )`.  For your `Tile`, this is not the case.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and ended up fixing the traceback problem. Except now my cover isn't removed so I'll have to do some messing around with my Tile class. Thank you for your answer and time.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.